# Booted up with low graphics, no mouse, no internet (driver failure?)

Tags: drivers

I just turned on my laptop and the gui is very low res compared to normal, the mouse is missing, and the internet no longer will connect.
I have an asus laptop so when I first got it I had to get special drivers to make the wifi work, so that is why I think it is some sort of failure to load drivers. I am at a loss of what do to, it worked fine just a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
I connected a mouse and it showed up so I could use that.
Then I went to 'additional drivers' and changed my gtx 960 driver (not in use, I had it installed but used the integrated graphics) from the one I set when I got the laptop to a different one (the open source one that was the) and then restart the pc and the internet and mouse and screen was fixed.